# Jquery - If span is < Num, Increment, addClass/s, removeClass/s

Tags: jquery

Just a seeing if any of you fellow pros could help me clean up or improve this little piece of code?

Plain ol english:

While span is less than number:

- Add class hide
- Increment number
- Add class show
- Remove both classes

It functions how I intend in this fiddle, but just wondering if there is a better way?

```
var $entrySizeClass = $(".entry-size-activity");
var $entrySizeNum = $entrySizeClass.text();

function entrySizeLoop() {
    setInterval(function() { // this code is executed every 3 seconds:
        $entrySizeClass.removeClass("entry-size-hide");
        $entrySizeClass.removeClass("entry-size-show");
        if($entrySizeNum < 105) {
           $entrySizeClass.addClass("entry-size-hide");
           setTimeout(function(){
               $entrySizeClass.addClass("entry-size-show");
           }, 100);    
            $entrySizeClass.text(parseInt($entrySizeClass.text())+1);
            $entrySizeNum++;
            console.log($entrySizeNum);
        }
    }, 5000);
}

$(entrySizeLoop);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rhysyg03/dnudhsmr/1/

Comment: If the code already works, then this is a code review.

Comment: No worries Jack, will keep that in mind for next time. Wasn't sure where the line was for works but sh** code haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments and suggestions:

1) The timed function is not running every 3 seconds, it's running every 5 (5000 milliseconds).

2) You can remove two classes at once: `$entrySizeClass.removeClass('entry-size-hide entry-size-show);`

3) Why are you both incrementing `$entrySizeNum` *and* `parseInt`ing `$entrySizeClass.text()`?  Why not just do:

```
$entrySizeNum++;
$entrySizeClass.text($entrySizeNum);
```

4) Your setInterval function never stops executing! To stop it, use `clearInterval`:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  if($entrySizeNum < 105) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, 5000);
  // rest of code
```